# Evapotranspiration in Modis

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modis, hydrology

I need the Evapotranspiration data for my study (The study area is located in Australia).
Somebody told me maybe I can use MOD 16 MODIS actual ET estimates. I could not find this data on earth explorer. Instead  I have found the following link http://www.ntsg.umt.edu/
which provide MOD 16 MODIS data. There are several folders in data folder which contain *.hdf files. Does anyone knows which folder I have to choose and how I can open the *.hdf files?(I tried to open one of *.hdf files in Arcmap. 3 bands are blank and one band is completely grey) .

Comment: Do you have access to GDAL? In which case check out http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/58688/convert-from-hdf-to-geotiff and http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/141776/read-hdf4-data-using-python depending on your data

Answer (score 3):

The first document that you should read is [MOD16_global_evapotranspiration_description.pdf](ftp://ftp.ntsg.umt.edu/pub/MODIS/NTSG_Products/MOD16/MOD16_global_evapotranspiration_description.pdf) where is pointed out that the MOD16 global evapotranspiration (ET)/ latent heat flux (LE)/ potential ET (PET)/ potential
LE (PLE) datasets are regular 1-km2 land surface ET datasets for the 109.03 Million km2 global vegetated land areas at 8-day, monthly and annual intervals.

The users should multiply 0.1 to get the real ET/PET values in mm/8day or mm/month, or mm/yr, and 1.0e4 to get LE/PLE in J/m2/day.

For the 8-day and monthly ET/LE/PET/PLE, annual LE/PLE, the valid value range is -32767-
32700.

```
Fill value, out of the earth 32767
Water body 32766
Barren or sparsely vegetated 32765
Permanent snow and ice 32764
Permanent wetland 32763
Urban or Built-up 32762
Unclassified 32761
```

For the annual ET/PET, the valid value range is 0- 65500.

```
Fill value, out of the earth 65535
Water body 65534
Barren or sparsely vegetated 65533
Permanent snow and ice 65532
Permanent wetland 65531
Urban or Built-up 65530
Unclassified 65529
```

The above information is very important for map algebra.

Next, you have to choose the tile(s) of your study areas. Australia has representation in (horizontal tile number, vertical tile number): (h29,v10), (h30,v10), (h31,v10 )... to ... (h31,v12).

Assuming that you are interested in the annual product (year 2000) for tile (h30,v11):

ftp://ftp.ntsg.umt.edu/pub/MODIS/NTSG_Products/MOD16/MOD16A3.105_MERRAGMAO/Y2000/

you have to download **MOD16A3.A2000366.h30v11.105.2013122030105.hdf**.

This product has 5 data subsets (ET_QC, PLE, PET, LE, ET). ArcMap should load these subsets without problems. The projection is sinusoidal.

On the other hand, the reason of your 3 blank and one grey datasets is probably due to inclusion of high values corresponding to Barren or sparsely vegetated, etc compared to ET, etc values. They need to be excluded with map algebra.

For example, considering (in QGIS) only ET data values without excluding "Barren or sparsely vegetated" (65533 value):

[image]

Considering only ET data values and excluding "Barren or sparsely vegetated" (65533 value) with map algebra in the raster calculator (the style used was a pseudocolor band renderer):

[image]

Comment: Xunik, thanks for your complete response.I was wondering How I can find the needed tile based on long/lat of area? Another thing, I need to calculate actual evatransporation time series to calibrate my Hydrological model. Do you think if it is a good Idea to use Modis ET imaginary? Thanks for your time.

Comment: @Mike For the first question you can look here: http://modis-land.gsfc.nasa.gov/pdf/sn_bound_10deg.txt.

Comment: I found two websites to find tiles and download data: https://daac.ornl.gov/cgi-bin/MODIS/GLBVIZ_1_Glb/modis_subset_order_global_col5.pl          http://landweb.nascom.nasa.gov/cgi-bin/developer/tilemap.cgi                        I loaded subset 0 ET_1 KM ModGrid (8 days). My problem is I am getteing Higher value for D008 (summer)  compare with D153 (Autumn) (My area located in Australia). Is there any reason for that? Any advise? Thanks

Comment: I am not a hidrologist but I think that's fine. I am basing my answer in these documents: http://www.australia.gov.au/about-australia/australian-story/austn-weather-and-the-seasons, http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1046/j.1365-2435.2000.00416.x/full